# A frequency que-related question.

Tags: probability

So O-levels are knocking on my door, and while practicing I found this problem:

"Issac wrote down six whole numbers on a piece of paper. The mean of these numbers is 10, the median is also 10 and the mode is 11. The smallest number is halved of the largest number. Find the six whole numbers."

I managed to get some numbers right, but not completely.

Would someone please solve this for me?

Comment: What does "que-related" mean?

Comment: What does "the mode is 11" mean?

Comment: @barakmanos the mode of a list of values is the value which appears most frequently

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Does that mean that $11$ appears at least once?

Comment: @barakmanos at the very least

Comment: List the 6 numbers from smallest to largest $a_1$ to $a_6$. Some consecutive values must be the same (or there is no mode). You can write down equations for the mean and median relating some values. The mode information will have to be used as trial and error. Are there 2 mode values? Are there 3? Exhaust the possibilities.

Comment: Also, what does "getting some numbers right" mean in this case?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $11$ appears at least twice, since its the (only) mode. So, our numbers are $11,11,a,b,c,d$.

Because of the median, we know that the two values in the middle are either $10,10$ or $11,9$.  In fact, this first possibility is impossible (if $10$ appears twice, then $11$ has to appear at least $3$ times to be the mode), so we necessarily have $11,9$ as the middle values.

Our values are then $a,b,9,11,11,c$, in increasing order.

From the mean, we know that $11 + 11 + 9 + a + b + c = 60$.

As a last piece of information, we know that $c = 2a$.

All we need to do then is find whole numbers $a\leq b\leq9$ for which 
$$
11 + 11+ 9 + a + b + 2a = 60 \implies\\
3a + b = 29
$$
At this point, it's just trial and error.  It turns out that $a = 7,b = 8$ is the only possibility.

Comment: What about 3 modal values? 4?

Comment: Doesn't $10$ have to be in the list, since it's the median?

Comment: @Paul what about it?  All I'm saying in the first paragraph is that $11$ appears *at least* twice.

Comment: @barakmanos no.  The median of a list of even numbers is the mean of the two in the middle.  The median of 0,0,1,2,10,20 is $1.5$.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution with 3 values of 11? I did not check.

Comment: OK, that explains why the entire question didn't make any sense to me...

Comment: @Masacroso the median does not need to be a whole number.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, I see your point.